# Numpy where - in function matches other column

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to generate a new df column with an np.where function. Specifically, I'd like to generate a binary variable depending on if the Identifier in a row is in a list of a Identifiers in a different dataframe. Please see function below.

This seems like a straightforward function - does anyone know why it does not work? Thank you for your help.

```
df2['ETF-Heavy?']=np.where(df2['ID'] in df1['ID'], 1,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using  `.isin`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,21,31]})

df2['ETF-Heavy?'] = np.where(df2['ID'].isin(df1['ID']) , 1,0)
print(df2)
```

**Output:**

```
   ID  ETF-Heavy?
0   1           1
1  21           0
2  31           0
```

Comment: Thank you very much